# How to check if text is a site to browse or something to search

Tags: webview, android-edittext

I want to check if *`string`* is a site or some words that should be searched using a search engine. For example when i use chrome

1. If i type google and press enter chrome searches the word using google as search engine
2. But if i type google.com it browses to site

Here i should check it. **But how?**

```
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: isValidUrl not works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can do better if uses 2 editText fields.
One for websites and another for google query.
While in that way :

answer to question 1 is

```
WebView webView=new WebView(Nameofthisactivity.this);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+string);
```

answer to question 2 is

```
WebView webView=new WebView(Nameofthisactivity.this);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webView.loadUrl(string);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course i can use 2 edittexts... but my question is how can i check if a string is a site to browse or text.

Comment: You could use android.webkit.URLUtil to test  : URLUtil.isValidUrl(url);       If it returns true,then it is a valid url,false otherwise.Then conclude which operation from above should be performed.

Comment: i deleted mine and accepted your answer please see my edits